# HTTP POST/PUT files with headers that are guaranteed to be returned on GET operations

Tags: apache, http

I would like to POST/PUT files on a web server with certain HTTP headers, and have the web server return those headers on each GET requests for those files.

Is there a way included inside the protocol to guarantee this, or is this behavior dependent on having a proprietary web server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web server. Most won't store data from request header fields.